# Unable to use tmuxp

Tags: python, tmux

I installed tmuxp using `sudo pip install --user tmuxp`. However I'm unable to load my profile `work.yaml`.
It throws error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pranav/.local/bin/tmuxp", line 7, in <module>
    from tmuxp import cli
ImportError: No module named tmuxp
```

I've followed https://github.com/tony/tmuxp instructions.

Comment: drop sudo and try again?

Comment: What did pip output? Using --user with sudo might make the module available only for root.

Comment: If I do not use sudo, getting `OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied`

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall: `pip uninstall tmuxp`

Assure the binary file is removed: `rm ~/.local/bin/tmuxp`

Reinstall: `pip install --user tmuxp`

Double check your python / pip configuration:

If the above doesn't work, there may be a larger issue with your pip installation, the problem may be a generic pip issue. 90% of the time this happens with `PATH`s from system's python mix up your user-level python.

Check `which pip`, `which python` and get an eye through tracebacks if your system's packages are mixing up with your local ones (e.g. `/usr/local/python3.7/site-packages` and `~/.somepath/python3.7/site-packages`.  If that is the case, consider clearing out all local pip packages and reinstalling pip through the [get-pip.py installer](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#installing-with-get-pip-py).